# How can I test a dropdown menu in Java from a generated selenium test case?

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, junit

I am converting one of my Selenium test cases to Java and I am having a problem.  The test involves checking links in drop down menus. My code is working sporadically on some of the links. Do I need to add this before each link test? I can make it a method if that is the case.

```
driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
try {
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.dropdown-toggle")).click();
}
catch (Exception e)  {
    new SendMail("janet.frank@rodale.com",to_email,"CSS Selector","Error in cssSelector execution");
    errorsFound = true;
}
```

Here is the method for the xpath:

```
private void executeXpath (String urlName, String value) { 
     String msg = ""; 
     String xPath = "(//a[contains(text(),'" + urlName + "')])[" + value + "]"; 
     try { 
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath)).click(); 
         checkUrl(urlName); 
     } catch (Exception e) { 
         msg = urlName + " test was not successful"; 
         new SendMail("janet.frank@rodale.com",to_email,urlName,msg); 
         errorsFound = true; 
     } 
 // driver.navigate().back(); 
    wait_fiveSeconds(); 
}
```

I have tried doing waits, executing the CSS dropdown method before each link but short of me staying hovered over the main header so that the dropdown stays visible does not work.

So I saw this code example posted, but what do I import so that I can create and Actions chain?

```
Actions action = new Actions(webdriver); 
WebElement we = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[13]/ul/li[4]/a")); 
action.moveToElement(we).build().perform();
```

I need to have my code execute the link and go to new pages but it does not seem to be doing that using the Actions API. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is the method for the xpath:

Comment: private void executeXpath (String urlName, String value)
 {
  String msg = "";
  String xPath = "(//a[contains(text(),'" + urlName + "')])[" + value + "]";

  try
     {
   driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath)).click();
            checkUrl(urlName);
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
      msg = urlName + " test was not successful";
      new SendMail("janet.frank@rodale.com",to_email,urlName,msg);
      errorsFound = true;
     }
 //    driver.navigate().back();
     wait_fiveSeconds();
 }

Comment: I have tried doing waits, executing the CSS dropdown method before each link but short of me staying hovered over the main header so that the dropdown stays visible does not work.  :(

Comment: So I saw this code example posted, but what do I import so that I can create and Actions chain??  Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
WebElement we = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[13]/ul/li[4]/a"));
action.moveToElement(we).build().perform();

Comment: I need to have my code execute the link and go to new pages but it does not seem to be doing that using the Actions API.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks to those who reformatted my question.  Does anyone know how I can fix this though??  My test is running inconsistently at displaying the dropdown and if the dropdown does not appear then the links to new pages do not work.  I really need this fixed ASAP!!!   Thanks.

Comment: I am not talking about the formatting I am talking about the original question about executing my dropdown links.  The code works sometimes and not others.  I amusing methods so I am not sure why it I am getting different results sporadically.

Comment: I used an answer from this question and I thought it worked but every so often it did not.  It seems my mouse needs to be resting on the page for it to work.  This defeats the purpose of an automated test, right??   Here is the question where I got the answer: How to perform mouseover function in Selenium WebDriver using Java?

Comment: This is my code:        hoverClick = action.moveToElement(toElement).build();
     hoverClick.perform();
     wait_fiveSeconds();
     hoverClick = action.moveToElement(subElement).click().build();